# testing objects for nothing and reflection

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting NullReferenceException on:

faxnum = Customer.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink.Phone.PhoneNumber

The null ref is on the DefaultFaxLink.  Since there isn't a fax number, the DefaultFaxLink isn't initialized and I know that if it were, I wouldn't get the error on the assignment.

So, my question is, is there a way I can trap the exception without having to test each object to see if it is nothing?

I just want to treat the entire right hand portion of a statement so that if any part is nothing, I just assign nothing to the left var.

Short of that, could I use reflection on the base object to evaluate each member and its sub-members and assign an empty value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Try-Catch block for NullReferenceException

```
Public Class Customer
    Public ContactLink As ContactLink
End Class

Public Class ContactLink
    Public Contact As Contact
End Class

Public Class Contact
    Public DefaultFaxLink As FaxLink
End Class

Public Class FaxLink
    Public Phone As Phone
End Class

Public Class Phone
    Public PhoneNumber As String
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim objCustomer As New Customer
    objCustomer.ContactLink = New ContactLink
    objCustomer.ContactLink.Contact = New Contact
    objCustomer.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink = New FaxLink

    Dim PhoneNumber As String = ""

    Try
        PhoneNumber = objCustomer.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink.Phone.PhoneNumber
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        PhoneNumber = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber) Then
        MsgBox("Fax number is..." & PhoneNumber)
    Else
        MsgBox("No fax number!")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function.

```
Public Class Customer

    Public Function GetFaxNumberSafe() As String

        If Me.ContactLink IsNot Nothing AndAlso
           Me.ContactLink.Contact IsNot Nothing AndAlso
           Me.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink IsNot Nothing AndAlso
           Me.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink.Phone IsNot Nothing Then

            Return Customer.ContactLink.Contact.DefaultFaxLink.Phone.PhoneNumber

        Else

            Return Nothing

        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

You could also set up your objects to lazy-load instantiate on access so you always have an object reference.

```
Public Class Customer

    Private _contactLink As New Lazy(Of ContactLink)()

    Public ReadOnly Property ContactLink As ContactLink
        Get
            Return _contactLink.Value
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I knew about the multiple if's for each member and the try-catch.  I was trying to not have to do that as I need to do this on multiple fields.  Is there a way to create a macro (like a #define) to wrap the statement like in the 'C' language?

Comment: Trapping the exception isn't really a good solution, because you won't necessarily know why the exception was thrown. I think you're trying to find an overly clever solution for a problem where the solution is simple. Any "clever" solution will add excessive overhead or code complexity that isn't necessary. If your goal is simply to make sure that those objects always exist, just create the objects. Lazy instantiate them, or create them in each class's constructor.

Comment: Hmm, you say that trapping the exception is not a good solution because you won't know why it was thrown however in your function solution you still don't know which property was Null so I believe they are as bad as each other

Comment: One is a proactive approach vs. a reactive approach. You should prefer performing a null check rather than trapping a null exception. The null check has way less overhead and is more explicit. What if the entire Customer object was null? What if the implementation inside the PhoneNumber property getter changes, and it throws a null reference exception? In these cases, the exception would be hidden, when it should remain unhandled to indicate a problem with the application.